# how to calculate sum of two field in same schema and save the result in another schema in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i have a two schema  i want to calculate the player1 and player2  score to save in another schema . note :- player1 and player2 both are in same schema and how to apply aggregation

i have a following list to apply and calculate the result

```
a) while creating the players and tournaments , calculate the totals(totalWin,totalTip) from players by aggregation.<br>
   e.g: player1,tournament1,tip=25,win=75
        player2,tounament1,tip=10,win=40
   Then the tournament 1 will have totalTip:25+10=35 and totalWin:75+40=115

e.g: player1,tournament2,tip=20,win=100
     player3,tournament2,tip=30,win=70
   Then the tournament 2 will have totalTip:20+30=50 and totalWin:100+70=170
   and so on for the tournament and players


b)perform the partial update on players:
  assume tournament 1 has 10 players , but we need to update the details of only 2 players (it could be any number).
  instead of all the players, only the players which needs to be update, should be passed.
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
what i have done till

### model floder in player_schema.js

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./tournament_schema')


const player_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  joining_date:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  tip:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  win:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  balance:{
    type:Number,
    required:true

  },
  tournament_id:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"tournament_datas"
  }

})

const players = mongoose.model("players_data",player_Schema);

module.exports = players;
```

### model floder in tournament_schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tournament_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({

  date:{
    type:String,
    required: true,

  },
  name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  total_win:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  total_tip:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  }

})


const tournaments_data = mongoose.model("tournaments_data" ,tournament_Schema);



module.exports = tournaments_data;
```

### controller folder in players_controllers.js

```
const db = require('../modal/player_schema');


exports.create_data = (req,res)=>{

  // const userExit = db.exists({_id:req.params.id});
  // if(userExit)
  // return console.log("user Exits");
  console.log("=====>",req.body);
  // return;
  const players = new db({

    joining_date : req.body.joining_date,
    name : req.body.name,
    tip : req.body.tip,
    win : req.body.win,
    balance : req.body.balance,

  });


  players.save((err,result)=>{
    if(err){
      res.json({masg:"error occure when create the data "})
    }else {
      console.log("data inserted successfully in database ");
      return  res.json({result:result,msg:"data inserted into data base"})
    }
  })


}




exports.get_all_data =  (req,res)=>{
  db.find({},(err,data) =>{
    if(!err){
      res.send(data);
    }else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
}


exports.get_by_id =(req,res)=>{
  const id = req.params.id;
  // db.findById(id,(err,data)
  db.findById(id,(err,data)=>{
      if(!err){
        console.log("data by id",data)
        res.json({"data by id":data})
      }else {
        console.log(err);
      }
  })
}

exports.update_data = (req,res) =>{
  const players ={
    joining_date : req.body.joining_date,
    name : req.body.name,
    tip : req.body.tip,
    win : req.body.win,
    balance : req.body.balance,
  }
  const id = req.params.id;
  db.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$set:players},{new:true},(err,data) =>{
    console.log("update data ==>",data);
    if(!err) {
      res.status(200).json({code:200,msg:"players updated successfully",
    updated_player:data})
  }else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
}



exports.delete_data =(req,res)=>{
  db.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id,(err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.status(200).json({code:200,msg:"players data deleted successfully"});
    }else {
      console.log("delete error",err);
    }
  })
}
```

### controller folder in tournament_controllers.js

```
const db = require('../modal/tournament_schema');


exports.create_data_for_tournamenet = (req,res)=>{
  const tournament_data = new db({
    date :req.body.date,
    name: req.body.name,
    total_win:req.body.total_win,
    total_tip:req.body.total_tip
  })

  tournament_data.save((err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.json({msg:"data created successfully"});
    }else {
      res.json({error:err})
      console.log("err ===>", err );
    }
  })
}




exports.all_tournament = (req,res)=>{
  db.find({},(err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.status(200).json({all_tournament:data});
    }else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}

exports.tournament_by_id =(req,res)=>{
  const id = req.params.id
  db.findById(id,(err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      console.log("data by id",data)
      res.json({"data by id":data})
    }else {
      console.log(err);
    }

  })
}

exports.tournament_update = (req,res)=>{
  const update_tournament =  {
    date:req.body.date,
    name:req.body.name,
    total_win:req.body.total_win,
    total_tip:req.body.total_tip

  }

  const id = req.params.id;

  db.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$set:update_tournament},{new:true},(err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.status(200).json({code:200,msg:"tournament is update",update_tournament:data})
    }else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })

}



exports.tournament_delete = (req,res)=>{
  db.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id,(err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
      res.json({msg:"tournament_removed successfully",tournament_deleted:data})
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In players_data table, there should be tournament_id field. And then after creating a player, there will be run update query for total_tip and total_win in tournaments_data table by tournament_id.

Comment: ok noted then after how to calculate score  of player1 and player2  and save in tournament model in where field name is total_win

Comment: i apply aggregation but doesn't work

Comment: Can you show aggregation query

Comment: db.aggregate(
  {$match: {
    _id
  }},
  { $project:{
    _id:620a1e623eb5ba9f355ac502,
    total_win:{$add: ["$win"]}
  }
    
  }
)